# SQL beginner : sub-query

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select tenant_name, tenant_dob
from tenant
where rental_no = (select rental_no
                    from rental
                    where apt_no = 203);
```

The question is that listing the name and DOB of tenants who live in apt 203. The query on the above is correct one. My coding is below. I know that I did not use sub-query statement. Actually, I can just simply memorize statement of sub-query for school exam questions, but I would like to know when do I have to use the sub-query, and why I have to use the sub-query. Also, please tell me things that I have to know about sub-query to use it.

```
select tenant_name, tenant_dob
from tenant
where rental_no = 203;
```

Comment: `rental_no` is not the same as `apt_no`.  You are using `=`, but `in` would more typically be used.  Or, even `join`.

Comment: You need to use a subquery (or other methods, like joins) when all the bits of data are not in the same table. apt_no is not in the TENANT table, so you need to fetch the rental number(s) corresponding to that apt_no. PAY CLOSE ATTENTION to what Gordon said: If there may be more than one rental number for an apartment (usually there are!) then your query will give you a runtime error. You CAN use the = sign if there is one rental number returned; but if there are several rentals (several tenants), use IN - and that will give you all the tenants, not just one, who are in apt_no = 203.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it's much better to use join instead.

```
select t.tenant_name, t.tenant_dob
from tenant t join rental r on t.rental_no = r.rental_no
where t.rental_no = apt_no = 203;
```

You join tenant and rental, so they are perceived as one by the database.
Next, you define your filter predicate, which is `apt_no = 203`.
Finally, you choose which attributes you want to return (`t.tenant_name, t.tenant_dob`).

That's conceptually proper way of solving this task in a relational database.

Subqueries are useful when your filtering (the where clause) is complex, and expressing it using joins would mess up your code. In that case, it can simplify your query a lot but in your case, it does the opposite.

**why I have to use the sub-query?** You want to select a row from table A based on some predicate in table B. You need a link between A and B. In you subquery you selected key in table B to find a proper row in table A.

Comment: I am not convinced in this particular case a join is warranted. If the tables are large, the join is expensive. With an apartment number in hand, the subquery goes over the "RENTAL" table once and retrieves a small number of rental numbers; then those are used in the outer query. Now, it is true that the Oracle optimizer will do the same thing for you (it will push the WHERE clause from the outer query into a made-up subquery of sorts), but in concept the subquery approach seems more natural and makes more sense if there was no optimizer.

Comment: @mathguy Conceptually, join is the right way to go if we're talking about relational database theory. DBMS knows our intentions and should prepare proper and optimized execution plan. What happens under the hood is out of our concern, as long as performance isn't critical.

Comment: The join solution will return a different result then the sub-query if there is a one-to-many relationship between `tenant` and `rental`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well, the solution with sub-query will fail in that scenario.. OP marked it as a correct one, so I assume there is only one row dependent in rental table.

Comment: Note - by "subquery solution" I mean the one using an IN condition, as mentioned by Gordon; I emphasized that point to the OP in an additional comment under the question itself.

Comment: There is no "fail" or "no fail". The sub-query simply returns something different. If you only want each tenant once the sub-query is the correct solution. If you want the tenant multiple times, the join is the correct solution. The two queries are **not** equivalent in what they mean.